# How to get a value from a hashtable entry

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, hashtable

I have put all of my form controls in a hashtable thus :-

```
 foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            myhash.Add(c.Name, c);

        }
```

amongst which are two radio buttons. I would like to get the value of the buttons, ie checked or unchecked, and assign them to a variable. How can I do that please. Thanks for all and any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach (Control c in hashtable.Values)
{
    if(c is RadioButton)
    {
        string name = x.Name;
        bool isChecked = (c as RadioButton).Checked;
    }
}
```

or if you know the name

```
(hashtable["name"] as RadioButton).Checked;
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you. Just the sort of simple and straightforward answer I was hoping for.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve a value by a key associated with it, basically control Name is a key in hashtable you've created. So if you know a name of controls you need to access:

```
var control = hash[radioButtonControlName] as RadioButton;
```

Otherwise using LINQ [OfType()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) and [List.ForEach()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx):

```
// OfType() does check whether each item in hash.Values is of RadioButton type
// and return only matchings
hash.Values.OfType<RadioButton>()
           .ToList()
           .ForEach(rb => { bool isChecked = rb.Checked } );
```

OR using `foreach` loop:
([there is a nice overview of misconception of the List.ForEach() usage](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx))

```
var radioButtons = hash.Values.OfType<RadioButton>();

foreach(var button in radioButons)
{
    bool isChecked = rb.Checked;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast the control that is the radio button to a [RadioButton Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.aspx) instance and then look at [the checked property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checked.aspx).  At least that would be how I've done this many times over in WebForms using similar classes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the hashtable in your code is an instance of Hashtable:

```
Hashtable myhash= new Hashtable();
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    myhash.Add(c.Name, c);
}
```

You can do this:

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in myhash)
{
    RadioButton rb = entry.Value as RadioButton;
    if (rb != null)
        bool checked = rb.Checked;
}
```

Also you can see the key of the hashmap entry with:

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in myhash)
{
    var componentName = entry.Key;
}
```

That will correspond with the name of the component that you put in the hashmap (c.Name).

Hope this help you.